# What problems can lead to a CuDNNError with ConvolutionND

Tags: chainer

I am using three-dimensional convolution links (with ConvolutionND) in my chain.

The forward computation run smoothly (I checked intermediate result shapes to be sure I understood correctly the meaning of the parameters of convolution_nd), but during the backward a `CuDNNError` is raised with the message `CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

The `cover_all` parameter of ConvolutionND as its default value of False, so from the doc I don't see what can be the cause of the error.

Here is how I defind one of the convolution layers :

```
self.conv1 = chainer.links.ConvolutionND(3, 1, 4, (3, 3, 3)).to_gpu(self.GPU_1_ID)
```

And the call stack is

```
File "chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
File "chainer/functions/connection/convolution_nd.py", line 118, in backward
    gy, W, stride=self.stride, pad=self.pad, outsize=x_shape)
File "chainer/functions/connection/deconvolution_nd.py", line 310, in deconvolution_nd
    y, = func.apply(args)
File chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
File "chainer/functions/connection/deconvolution_nd.py", line 128, in forward
    return self._forward_cudnn(x, W, b)
File "chainer/functions/connection/deconvolution_nd.py", line 105, in _forward_cudnn
    tensor_core=tensor_core)
File "cupy/cudnn.pyx", line 881, in cupy.cudnn.convolution_backward_data
File "cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx", line 975, in cupy.cuda.cudnn.convolutionBackwardData_v3
File "cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx", line 461, in cupy.cuda.cudnn.check_status
cupy.cuda.cudnn.CuDNNError: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

So are there special points to take care of when using `ConvolutionND` ?

A failing code is for instance :

```
import chainer
from chainer import functions as F
from chainer import links as L
from chainer.backends import cuda

import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

chainer.global_config.cudnn_deterministic = False

NB_MASKS = 60
NB_FCN = 3
NB_CLASS = 17

class MFEChain(chainer.Chain):
    """docstring for Wavelphasenet."""
    def __init__(self,
                 FCN_Dim,
                 gpu_ids=None):
        super(MFEChain, self).__init__()

        self.GPU_0_ID, self.GPU_1_ID = (0, 1) if gpu_ids is None else gpu_ids
        with self.init_scope():
            self.conv1 = chainer.links.ConvolutionND(3, 1, 4, (3, 3, 3)).to_gpu(
                self.GPU_1_ID
            )

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        ### Pad input ###
        processed_sequences = []
        for convolved in inputs:
            ## Transform to sequences)
            copy = convolved if self.GPU_0_ID == self.GPU_1_ID else F.copy(convolved, self.GPU_1_ID)
            processed_sequences.append(copy)

        reprocessed_sequences = []
        with cuda.get_device(self.GPU_1_ID):
            for convolved in processed_sequences:
                convolved = F.expand_dims(convolved, 0)
                convolved = F.expand_dims(convolved, 0)
                convolved = self.conv1(convolved)

                reprocessed_sequences.append(convolved)

            states = F.vstack(reprocessed_sequences)

            logits = states

            ret_logits = logits if self.GPU_0_ID == self.GPU_1_ID else F.copy(logits, self.GPU_0_ID)
        return ret_logits

def mfe_test():
    mfe = MFEChain(150)
    inputs = list(
        chainer.Variable(
            cp.random.randn(
                NB_MASKS,
                11,
                in_len,
                dtype=cp.float32
            )
        ) for in_len in [53248]
    )
    val = mfe(inputs)
    grad = cp.ones(val.shape, dtype=cp.float32)
    val.grad = grad
    val.backward()
    for i in inputs:
        print(i.grad)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mfe_test()
```

Comment: Did you check the version of cudnn? Does it compatible with your CUDA version?

Comment: Yes the two are compatible (cuda 9.2 and cudnn 7.1.4 for cuda 9.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cupy.cuda.cudnn.convolutionBackwardData_v3 is incompatible with some specific parameters, as described in [an issue in official github](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/3874).

Unfortunately, the issue only dealt with deconvolution_2d.py (not deconvolution_nd.py), therefore the decision-making about whether cudnn is used or not failed in your case, I guess.

you can check your parameter by confirming

1. check whether dilation parameter (!=1) or group parameter (!=1) is passed to the convolution.
2. print chainer.config.cudnn_deterministic, configuration.config.autotune, and configuration.config.use_cudnn_tensor_core.

Further support may be obtained by raising an issue in the official github.

The code you showed is much complicated.

To clarify the problem, the code below would help.

```
from chainer import Variable, Chain
from chainer import links as L
from chainer import functions as F

import numpy as np
from six import print_

batch_size = 1
in_channel = 1
out_channel = 1

class MyLink(Chain):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLink, self).__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            self.conv = L.ConvolutionND(3, 1, 1, (3, 3, 3), nobias=True, initialW=np.ones((in_channel, out_channel, 3, 3, 3)))

    def __call__(self, x):
        return F.sum(self.conv(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_link = MyLink()
    my_link.to_gpu(0)
    batch = Variable(np.ones((batch_size, in_channel, 3, 3, 3)))
    batch.to_gpu(0)
    loss = my_link(batch)
    loss.backward()
    print_(batch.grad)
```

Comment: As desciribed in [NVIDIA's official site](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html), the deterministic implementation is incompatible to dilation!=1.

Comment: I set the cudnn_deterministic to false but still have the problem. I didn't pass dilatation or group parameter to the ConvolutionND constructor.
I am trying to build a minimal example showing the issue and will update the question with it.

Comment: More simple test may help...

    from chainer import links as L

Comment: I tried your test and it worked. After investigation the problem is dependant from the input size so I guess there is an out of memory problem causing the error